# Kafka Connect to AKS Kafka Cluster Security Config

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

**Brief intro:**

I am having difficulty understanding exactly what needs to be done to allow my on-prem Kafka Connect client to successfully connect to Azure Kubernetes Kafka Cluster.

**Full detail:**

Starting from Azure, I have a fully configured AKS Kafka cluster running, this has been set up using Helm and Strimzi. The Kafka cluster was set up with this script:

```html
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-kafka-cluster
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.0.0
    replicas: 1
    listeners:
    - name: plain
      port: 9092
      type: internal
      tls: false
    - name: tls
      port: 9093
      type: internal
      tls: true
      authentication:
        type: tls
    - name: external
      port: 9094
      type: loadbalancer
      tls: true
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 1
      default.replication.factor: 1
      min.insync.replicas: 1
      log.message.format.version: "3.0"
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 1
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

As you can see, this has an external load balancer configured on port 9094 which, from everything I can find, should be all I need to do to expose this correctly to the internet. The services appear in my cluster and it looks good. I have checked in my Azure Portal that this exists too. So I think Azure is ready...

---

Now for the client on-prem, I am running a Linux box with Docker and the Debezium/connect image for ease of use right now.

The connect container is pointing at the `bootstrap.server=<azure-external-IP:9094>` which was the external load balancer that Strimzi created.

The only other thing to get this to connect successfully, as far as I am aware, is I need to make some changes to the *connect-distributed.properties* file to set up the client to use SSL.
These changes are:

- Add some certificates into a keystore/truststore.
- Add some SSL configuration for the client, producer and consumer in `connect-distributed.properties`

For the first bullet point:
Which certificate from Kubernetes do I need exactly, is it the ca.crt?
Where exactly does this certificate need to go and is there a specific setup that I need to follow because I am using docker?

For the second bullet point:
Which exact configuration do I need to follow to get this to work? I assume it is similar to this https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/encryption.html#kconnect-long, but I don't know for sure.

There are so many different tutorials online and I am struggling to know which one is correct for this exact situation. Any help at all on this would be incredibly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit** - To add Docker details, the Debezium/Connect Image details, Strimzi Version and error logs

Docker info:
Version-20.10.12
API version-1.41

Debezium/Connect:image
I am just using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/debezium/connect) base image and spinning it up as described in that link but with my bootstrap_Server added in.

Strimzi:
Version is 0.28.0

Kafka:
Azure Kubernetes Version is 3.0.0
Kafka Connect Version is 2.7.1

Error information is below!

```html
2022-03-20 13:36:42,170 INFO   ||  [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed   [org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager]
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1647783402169, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1647783402270) timed out at 1647783402170 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call. Call: fetchMetadata
2022-03-20 13:37:12,170 INFO   ||  App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered   [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]
2022-03-20 13:37:12,171 INFO   ||  [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed   [org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager]
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1647783432170, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=-9223372036854775709) timed out at 9223372036854775807 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call. Call: fetchMetadata
2022-03-20 13:37:12,180 INFO   ||  Metrics scheduler closed   [org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics]
2022-03-20 13:37:12,180 INFO   ||  Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter   [org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics]
2022-03-20 13:37:12,180 INFO   ||  Metrics reporters closed   [org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics]
2022-03-20 13:37:12,180 ERROR  ||  Stopping due to error   [org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:70)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:51)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:97)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:80)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1647783432168, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1647783432269) timed out at 1647783432169 after 1 attempt(s)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:64)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1647783432168, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1647783432269) timed out at 1647783432169 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes
```

Comment: Can you share your `Docker and the Debezium/connect image` ? What is version of strimzi operator  `0.28.0` or something else?  Is the version of Kafka same in your docker file of kafka connect ?  +  Share some logs of error.

Comment: Hi @Faaiz, I have edited the original post with hopefully enough information. If anything else would help, let me know and I'll dig it out. Thanks!

Comment: Kafka shouldn't use load balancers. Clients must communicate with individual brokers. The Strimzi documentation discusses how to expose the cluster, but you've not shown that config... And why not use Strimzi to also deploy KafkaConnect?

Comment: Ah, but you do need an external listener so which service with this should I be aiming for? Strimzi doc's show various ways to do it and load balancer was one of them. Or am I completely in the wrong area here...? And I have not used Strimzi for Connect mainly because I was just hoping to do a quick test of this and it is on-prem while the cluster is in AKS. So thought it might be simpler, I could be wrong again though.